# Smalltalk: how to modify self behaviour

Tags: mocking, metaprogramming, smalltalk

I'm porting my favorite Java/JavaScript Mocktito library to Smalltalk. I'm currently at the stage of implementing Spy for stubbing real objects. My problem arises when a spyed object invokes it's own method which is stubbed. Instead of:

```
self aMethod.
```

I'd rather want to delegate the call to the spy object:

```
spyObject aMethod.
```

Here is a scenario test for the expected behavior:

```
realObject := RealObjectForTesting new.
spyedObject := Spy new: realObject.
spyedObject when: #accesorWhichReturnsValue thenReturn: 'stubbed value'.

spyedObject accesorWhichCallsSelf.

self assert: (spyedObject verify: #accesorWhichReturnsValue).
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You make your "spy" be a "wrapper" object that only implements `doesNotUnderstand:` and then swap it for the real object using `become:`.

The spy's `doesNotUnderstand:` method will be called for all messages, and you can then e.g. log its argument (which is a Message object) and send it to the original object.

If you browse implementers of `doesNotUnderstand:` in your Smalltalk image you may find a couple of examples (e.g. in Squeak there is `MessageCatcher` and `ObjectViewer`).

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the `RealObjectUnderTest`'s `CompiledMethod`s directly, using the [ObjectsAsMethodsWrapper library](http://www.squeaksource.com/ObjectsAsMethodsWrap.html). This provides a convenient API to install and remove the wrappers, together with some convenient predefined wrappers.

These would intercept self-sends because the wrappers are installed in the real object's method dictionary, and thus may perform arbitrary changes to the message before passing it on to the underlying `CompiledMethod`.

While [my example](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2012/08/31/intercession-without-source-changes) shows how to memoize a method call without touching source code, it should provide you with the basic knowledge required to mock out method calls.

This particular technique does have a limitation: it intercepts self sends to messages that the class itself defines. So if `Foo` subclasses `Bar` and you install wrappers on `Foo`, you won't intercept messages that form part of `Bar`'s protocol (unless of course you wrap those too).

You *won't* be able to intercept `ifTrue:ifFalse:`, `timesRepeat` or similar messages in a Squeak or Pharo image (and likely in GNU Smalltalk too), because those are not message sends: compile-time transformations inline these message sends into jump bytecodes. (The illusion of a message send is relatively convincing because the `Decompiler` knows how to untransform the bytecodes back into `ifTrue:ifFalse:` or whatever.)

Comment: -1? Really? If it's factually incorrect you'd best explain why.

Comment: +1 - This is the most complete way to do what was requested and is in my opinion the best solution to the problem.  Frank explained the pros and cons quite well and I would suggest that this is the best way to go.  He saved me from writing the same thing myself.  Having said that, this is an advanced Smalltalk technique.  If you need extra information on how to do it, just ask.  Thanks Frank.

Comment: + 1 Yes, that’s the solution I’d go for as well.

Answer (score 2):

Smalltalk doesn't have a built-in mechanism for intercepting sends to self, so you'll have to resort to exotic measures.

Probably the easiest way to do it would be to dynamically steal methods from the original object. Your spy would replace the target using #become:, as Bert suggests. Then, when the spy receives a message, instead of forwarding the message to the original object, you'd look up the selector in its class and execute it with the spy as the receiver. The mechanism for executing a compiled method against an arbitrary receiver will vary from dialect to dialect. In Squeak it's CompiledMethod class>>receiver:withArguments:executeMethod:.

As I said, this is pretty exotic—you'll need to generate a custom class for the spy when it's created, and ensure that it has the same structure as the target object so that the compiled methods will work correctly with the new receiver. You'll also have to copy the state of the target into the spy, and back to the orignal object when you're done spying. Finally, you'll have to find a place to stash the target, since the state of the spy has to match that of the target. It's all doable, but it's not simple. You'll be dynamically generating classes and methods, which requires low-level understanding of the system.

Comment: in addition, i would say it doesn't makes sense as to me: